# dplyr style count if by group in r

Tags: r

e.g.

```
diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  summarise(pct_price_above_350 = (count(price > 350) / n()))
```

> Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `pct_price_above_350`.
> x no applicable method for 'group_vars' applied to an object of class "logical"
> ℹ Input `pct_price_above_350` is `(count(price > 351)/n())`.
> ℹ The error occurred in group 1: cut = "Fair".

The goal of the above block was to return the percent in each group that have a price above 350. How could I do that? tidyverse/dplyr preferred but I'll take what I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count` needs a data.frame or tibble as input.  We can use `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  summarise(pct_price_above_350 = (sum(price > 350) / n()), .groups = 'drop')
```

Or `mean`

```
diamonds %>% 
 group_by(cut) %>% 
 summarise(pct_price_above_350 = (mean(price > 350) ), .groups = 'drop')
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Accepting when time limit falls off. Aside, what is .groups = drop doing?

Comment: @DougFir In the new version, if we don't specify that, there will be a default option to drop only the last grouping variable (if there are more than one).  Here, it will drop the cut group, IN the output, you will have ``summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)` To avoid that notification, I used along with the fact that it will make sure that there won't be any groups (if there are more than one group)